# XPath - выбрать промежуток данных до и после определенных элементов

Tags: xpath

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>H2</h2>
<p>P</p>
<div><code>Python code</code></div>
<div><code>JS code</code></div>
<p>Example</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот есть такой HTML код.
Хочу написать XPath для выборки всех данных в тегах `code`, т.е. мне нужен список в конце с элементами `<code>Python code</code>` и `<code>JS code</code>`.

Проблема заключается в том, что нужен такой XPath, который бы собирал все теги `code`, которые вложены в дивы перед тегом `p` в котором `text()='Example'`.

Играюсь с `following-sibling` и `preceding-sibling` и не могу подобрать нужный икспас.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищем `code`, который вложен в `div`, относительно которого первой следующей нодой, не содержащей дочерний `code`, является `p` с текстом `Example` :

```
//code[ancestor::div/following-sibling::*[not(.//code)][1][self::p][text()='Example']]
```

```js
const xpath = "//code[ancestor::div/following-sibling::*[not(.//code)][1][self::p][text()='Example']]";

function getElementByXpath(xpathToExecute){
  var result = [];
  var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(xpathToExecute, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
  for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ ){
    result.push( nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i) );
  }
  return result;
}

console.log( getElementByXpath(xpath) );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <code>dont touch me 1</code>
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <p>P</p>
    <div>
      <code>dont touch me 2</code>
    </div>
    <div>
      <code>dont touch me 3</code>
    </div>
    <code>dont touch me 4</code>
    <p>Example</p>
    <code>dont touch me 5</code>
    <div>
      <code>dont touch me 6</code>
    </div>
    <div>
      <code>dont touch me 7</code>
    </div>
    <p>Invalid Example</p>
    <div>
      <code>Python code</code>
    </div>
    <div>
      <code>JS code</code>
    </div> 
    <p>Example</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавьте или перенесите `<div><code>Python code</code></div>
<div><code>JS code</code></div>
<code>dont touch me 3</code>
<p>Example</p>` в конец и посмотрите, что получится

Comment: Спасибо; пофиксил-отредактировал

Answer (score 1):

Ищем div'ы, за которыми сразу следует параграф с текстом Example, и берем дочерние code

```
//div[following-sibling::p[1][text()='Example']]/code
```

Comment: Заметка: в вашем случае разыскивается не первая нода после div, а первая нода параграфа, т.е. игнорируются все ноды между дивом и первым параграфом. Правда, тут на усмотрение автора: вдруг нет нужды в данной дотошности.

Comment: да, первый после див параграф.  Я не знаю, правильнее ли будет `following-sibling::*[1][name() = 'p' and text()='Example']` - это html, там все что угодно, включая текстовые ноды, может быть